# Juju bootstrap on local machine gives an error

Tags: juju

trying to use juju in a local environment. Here is my ~/.juju/environments.yaml file:

```
environments:
  sample:
    type: local
    control-bucket: juju-a14dfae3830142d9ac23c499395c2785999
    admin-secret: 6608267bbd6b447b8c90934167b2a294999
    default-series: oneiric
    juju-origin: distro
    data-dir: /home/matteo/juju
```

the path /home/matteo/juju exists. But when I type juju bootstrap here is the output:

```
2011-10-16 00:07:32,367 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'sample' (type: local)...
2011-10-16 00:07:32,367 INFO Checking for required packages...
2011-10-16 00:07:32,650 INFO Starting networking...
too many values to unpack
2011-10-16 00:07:32,897 ERROR too many values to unpack
```

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT:

after restarting my pc now it shows this:

```
2011-10-17 00:02:13,850 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'sample' (type: local)...
2011-10-17 00:02:13,850 INFO Checking for required packages...
2011-10-17 00:02:14,142 INFO Starting networking...
errore: Impossibile avviare la rete default
errore: Requested operation is not valid: network is already active

Command '['virsh', 'net-start', 'default']' returned non-zero exit status 1
2011-10-17 00:02:14,176 ERROR Command '['virsh', 'net-start', 'default']' returned     non-zero exit status 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two separate issues.

1. libvirt requires the user to be in the libvirt group. The login shell/desktop session that installed the libvirt package unfortunately won't have the groups active, till the next login. The easiest thing to do is to just logout/login.
2. We had some localization issues with the release. A fix <s>is in our review queue and it should be available from the ppa by the end of the week</s> has landed in the PPA.
   https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/873335

Comment: What ppa do I have to add? Because so far nothing changed.

Comment: The trunk daily build PPA is ppa:juju/pkgs

Comment: last update brings the right bugfix! It's working now! So cool!